# jQuery mobile ajax navigation

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am just getting my teeth into jQuery mobile (and so far it looks really interesting).

I read a [great tutorial on elated.com](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/jquery-mobile-what-can-it-do-for-you/flip-transition.html), one part of which was about page transitions/ajax navigation. This looks great (on my iPhone) but if you look at the source it's all flat html on the same page.

What i want/need is to point to another url and for ther same effect to happen if possible.

I have been reading [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html) info about data-url but I cant seem to get anything to work.

Here is some very rough example code that obviosuly doesnt work:

```
<p><a href="#" data-url="test.html" data-transition="flip">My test link</a></p>
```

What is the right code? Is it even possible?

Comment: If you mean an external (not a reference to an id on the same page), have you tried simply putting the url you want in the href of the 'a' tag?  That's how a lot of other mobile frameworks do it.

Comment: Yes, was about to say im being an idiot :s that works. cheers

Answer (score 2):

try `<a href="test.html">link</a>`

seems too obvious? ;)

`data-url` is an attribute that a page div has, when it's been loaded. All pages are AJAX-loaded to the current DOM and they get this attribute to be easy found.

Answer (score 0):

From http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

Default link behavior: Ajax

To enable animated page transitions, all links that point to an external page (ex. products.html) will be loaded via Ajax. To do this unobtrusively, the framework parses the link's href to formulate an Ajax request (Hijax) and displays the loading spinner. All this happens automatically by jQuery Mobile.

If the Ajax request is successful, the new page content is added to the DOM, all mobile widgets are auto-initialized, then the new page is animated into view with a page transition.

Answer (score 0):

add the tag: `data-ajax="false"` to anything you want to expliticly load a new page for, eg:

```
<a href="xyz.html" data-ajax="false">Link</a>
```

Alternatively you can use the native anchor `target` tag